# Calculating Sales Tax for a US State in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to calculate sales tax for a project and I can't get it to work. Needless to say, I'm still learning javascript.  Here's how it works: If the buyer selects New Jersey, I want to apply a 7% sales tax to the order.  Everywhere else goes to zero.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle project: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnOHFS/hpdnmjfL/

Here's my basic form HTML (skipping the opening and closing tags, etc.)

```
<div id="public">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="city">CITY</label>
                                  <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="city input-small form-control" placeholder="CITY"/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="state">STATE</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" id="state" onChange="taxRate()">
                                      <option value="">N/A</option>
                                      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>  
                                    </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="zipCode">ZIP CODE</label>
                                  <input id="zip" type="text" size="6" autocomplete="off" class="zipcode form-control" placeholder="ZIP CODE"/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div> <!-- Closes Public -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                <label>ORDER INFORMATION</label>                                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>SUBTOTAL: <b>$<span id="order_subtotal">100</span></b></label>                                                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>TAXES: <b><span id="order_tax" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>                                                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>ORDER TOTAL: <b><span id="order_total" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>                                                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
function taxRate() {
    var tax_rate = .07;
    var order_taxes = 0;
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("order_subtotal").value;
    subtotal = parseInt(subtotal);
    var total = 0;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var selection = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selection == 'New Jersey') {
      order_taxes += tax_rate * subtotal;
    } 
    if (selection == 'else') {
    order_taxes = 0;
    }
    if (selection == 'New Jersey') {
    tax_percent = tax_rate * 100;
    } 
    if (selection == 'else') {
    tax_percent = 0;
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('order_tax');
    el.textContent = order_taxes;

    var total = subtotal + order_taxes;
    var el1 = document.getElementById('order_total');
    el1.textContent = total;

}
```

Here are my questions.
 1.  What am i doing wrong?
 2.  How do I pass tax_percent from this javascript into the html for submittal to Stripe?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you load your JavaScript before or after the HTML block? Does your Console output anything?

Comment: @ErikEngervall I've only tried it in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your fiddle is that the `taxRate()` function is not a global function and so it can't be called from an inline html attribute event handler. This is because by default JSFiddle wraps the JS in an `onload` handler. Use the JS settings menu (from top-right corner of the JS window) to change the "load type" to one of the "no wrap" options.

Then you've got a problem getting the order total value, because you try to get the element `.value` when it is a span, so you need to use `.innerHTML`.

The next thing is that your `state` variable is set equal to the *value* of the current selection of the select element. So it will be `'NJ'`, or `'AK'`, etc. (Or an empty string if nothing is selected.) So when you try to set the `selection` variable to `state.options[state.selectedIndex].value` that won't work because `state` is a string. Test your existing `state` variable against `'NJ'`:

```
if (state == 'NJ')
```

You also have a test `if (selection == 'else')` which won't do anything because even if your `selection` variable worked its value would never be the *string* `'else'`. I think you just want an `else` statement there, except that what that block actually does is just set `order_taxes = 0` and `order_taxes` has already been set to a default of `0` at the point of declaration. So you don't need that part at all.

Then you've got another `if` testing for New Jersey that could be combined with the first one. It's setting a `tax_percent` variable that isn't declared, so add a declaration for that with `var` at the top of your function.

Also, because of the way JS does floating point maths, `100 * 0.07` comes out to be `7.000000000000001`. You probably want to round that off to two decimal places for the cents amount (which in this case would be no cents, but obviously if the order total wasn't such a round number you might get some number of cents in the taxes).

> *How do I pass tax_percent from this javascript into the html for submittal to Stripe?*

One way is to add a hidden input to your form and set its value from JS:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tax_percent" name="tax_percent">

document.getElementById('tax_percent').value = tax_percent;
```

Putting that all together:

```
function taxRate() {
    var tax_rate = .07;
    var order_taxes = 0;
    var tax_percent = 0;
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("order_subtotal").innerHTML;
    subtotal = parseInt(subtotal);
    var total = 0;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    if (state === 'NJ') {
      order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
      tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('order_tax');
    el.textContent = order_taxes;

    var total = subtotal + order_taxes;
    var el1 = document.getElementById('order_total');
    el1.textContent = total;
    document.getElementById('tax_percent').value = tax_percent;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hpdnmjfL/5/

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  Only issue I have is I need to pass in tax_percent in a hidden field for rails/stripe purposes.  Is there anything special I need to do for that?

Comment: As it happens I was just adding that to my answer. (Didn't see that requirement at first.) Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: You're a saint and a scholar.  Thanks!