# Stripe and tax_percent in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So I've got my rails app selling subscriptions to access content.  I'm temporarily inserting a hidden field in the check-out form to pass tax_percent to Stripe's API, but it keeps showing up in the Stripe dashboard as null.  The tax is only for NJ and is a straight 7% if the buyer is also in NJ.  I'm calculating the sales tax via a javascript call ([Calculating Sales Tax for a US State in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214372/calculating-sales-tax-for-a-us-state-in-javascript/38214653)), which then pushes the value to the subscription#create action.  Except it ain't working.

Here's what the line looks like in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tax_percent" name="tax_percent">
<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
```

Yes, I need to build a Ruby method to calculate this on the server side, but for now, this is fine.

Here's what shows up in the logs:

```
Processing by Koudoku::SubscriptionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TokenValueHere", "tax_percent"=>"7", "subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"5", "credit_card_token"=>"OtherTokenValue", "last_four"=>"undefined", "card_type"=>"undefined"}, "owner_id"=>"72"}
```

So you see that tax_percent appears to be outside the subscription object, yet plan_id is not, but they're right next to each other in the checkout form.

How do I get this tax_percent to hit the Stripe API properly??

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `f.hidden_field` inside the subscription object while your manual `<input>` is not, you ask? It’s because your manual input doesn’t use the naming convention for form fields that `hidden_field` automatically applies.

As the [docs for `#hidden_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/hidden_field) show, your hidden field `plan_id` actually has a `name` attribute of `subscription[plan_id]`, not `plan_id`. Another hidden field has to use the same `subscription[…]` convention for its value to be automatically put inside the hash at `params["subscription"]`.

You can automatically make your `tax_percent` hidden field adhere to this naming convention by using the standalone form helper [`hidden_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field):

```
<%= hidden_field :subscription, :tax_percent %>
<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
```

Comment: Can I use my javascript calculator output, which is document.getElementById('tax_percent').value = tax_percent; to inject that tax percent value into the ruby hidden_field: <%= hidden_field :subscription, :tax_percent %> ??

Comment: I get an error when I make this change: undefined method `tax_percent' for Subcription

Comment: @JohnOHFS Ah, I didn’t notice that the default `value` for that hidden field would be `@subscription.tax_percent`. If you don’t want to define a `tax_percent` method for your `Subscription` model, you can give the field a different value such as `0.07` by writing `<%= hidden_field :subscription, :tax_percent, value: '0.07' %>`.

Comment: @JohnOHFS And yes, setting the hidden field’s `value` with JavaScript should work like any other `<input>`. The browser will submit the hidden field’s last-set value along with other form values when it submits the form to the URL at the `<form>`’s `action` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, @Rory-Okane